# How could I spice this logo up?

Tags: logo, critique

I am currently working on starting a small business(less than 10 transactions a month), but in order to get any support from the suppliers, I need to create a logo and website.

So I would appreciate any feedback on this preliminary logo.

The business is called **Fremont Resoles**, it is a climbing shoe repair shop based out of Wyoming.

[image]

Comment: Thinking about how your logo is going to be used in context will help you clean things up. Is the black box part of your logo? How will that look shrunk WAY down on a business card? How do you imagine it will be used on your website? Quickly mocking up (or even just loosely sketching) some of the places it will be used can be really helpful in making sure your logo reads well in different situations. FWIW, I thought the image below the FR was a woodpecker! I'd consider turning the shoe to a different angle, or even just flat on its sole.

Comment: You can have a look at the critique guideline and see if you can make your question a bit more precise! http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work

Comment: Give us more to info to help understand your intent. Why did you reverse the F? Why that particular typeface? Why one shoe vs. two? Why did you place it at that angle? Why the big black box? What kind of 'vibe' are you trying to communicate with your logo? Who's your target demographic? Who's your competition? How will this logo be used? Etc.

Comment: I recommend that you don't limit yourself to F and R but rather write out your name. Your logo is your identity and thus should contain your name. Look at the logo of other companies. Walmart, Amazon, Microsoft,...they all wrote their name in the logo. Not every company does it. KFC for example uses their initials in their logo

Answer (score 1):

- remove the F and R.
- use a simple, easy-to-read sans-serif font. I suggest Droid Sans.
- make the logo a square. Why is it floating in the bottom-right corner?
- rotate the shoe to be sitting upright, horizontally, as a shoe would touch the ground naturally when walking.
  place the shoe above the name of the business. Write out the name of the business in smallcaps.
- remove some detail from the shoe, go for more of a silhouette look.

Comment: it is a "climbing shoe repair", so upright horizontally may not be the way to go either.

Comment: well upside down vertically isn't the direction of 'climbing', now is it?

Comment: haha no, not unless you are really bad at it haha